# how to use paginate with association models?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i want to paginate with two models association how to do this ..?

this is the find statment that i want to paginate it

```
$gallery =$this->Section->Gallery->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Gallery.section_id'=>86)));
```

// what i put here

```
  var $paginate = array(
         'Section'=>array(
         'limit' => 3,
         'page' => 1,
         'conditions' => array('Gallery.section_id'=>86)
         )

         );
```

// what i put here also

```
$this->set('section', $this->paginate());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather Section hasMany Gallery.
**If you want to paginate by the number of galleries you would need this**

```
var $paginate = array(
     'Gallery'=>array(
         'limit' => 3,
         'page' => 1,
         'conditions' => array('section_id'=>86))
  );

 //in your function
 $this->paginate('Gallery');
```

I hope his helps!